# Why can't a const pointer be set afterwards?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants

I know this is probably a trivial question. What is the logic behind not being able to set a const pointer after its declaration? It's not as if allocating memory will change the starting address which is what the const refers to. So why can't this...

```
int* const p;
p = new int [10];
```

... be done... which also prohibits the passing of a const pointer into a function?

Comment: Don't you *assign* the pointer returned by the `new` call to `p`? So, clearly you are changing the address it points to. I don't understand what you mean by the “prohibits the passing of a const pointer into a function” thing.

Comment: Right. But the first value is undefined. So it's as if the pointer doesn't have a value that counts. The first value that will count is the one to be given during assignment. So what I was asking is, why should it matter if the ONE assignment is done during declaration or at a later line? There's only going to be ONE official assignment anyway.

Comment: @dspfnder C++ doesn't have a concept of whether default-initialized values "count" or are valid. This is why Clang prohibits the creation of `const` values without explicit initialization.

Comment: @dspfnder: _"why should it matter if the ONE assignment is done during declaration or at a later line?"_ Because that's not true. The "assignment during declaration" is not an assignment. It is an initialisation.

Comment: @dspfnder Do you have a Java background by chance? A `const` pointer in C++ is not equivalent to a `final` reference in Java.

Answer (score 9):

**This is the entire purpose of `const`.**

`const` stands for "constant", and means the object cannot be assigned to.

If you want the pointer to be a variable, don't make it `const`.

I suspect you were expecting your assignment to be allowed because it was the first ever assignment to that object. You were wrong! This is the purpose of *initialisation*, which you are not presently using.

I'm guessing you meant to write:

```
int* const p = new int[10];
```

---

But I worry that you have more fundamental misconceptions here. For example:

> It's not as if allocating memory will change the starting address

Yes, it absolutely, completely will.

When your `p` comes into existence, it has an unspecified value. Its value is not a "starting address" that you can use.

Then you assign to it (though you ought to have initialised instead). It takes on the value equals to the pointer returned by `new`. That pointer has no relationship to anything previous in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Allocating memory does change the address.  For instance if we have

```
int * foo;
foo = new int[bar];
```

`foo` is uninitialized and has a garbage value.  Then `foo = new int[bar];` assigns to `foo` a new address that is the start of a block of `bar` `int`s.

Now when you have

```
int* const p;
```

The pointer is `const` so we cannot change it after it is initialized.

Comment: "it stores some address" is not really an accurate way to describe an uninitialized pointer.  It's illegal to read from an uninitialized value, and if you do, two reads of the same variable might not give back the same address.

Comment: @BenVoigt is this better?

Comment: Actually the line `int* const p;` won't even compile, since you cannot declare a `const` and leave it un-initialized.

Answer (score 2):

### Short version

The way you are defining the pointer means that it is `const` for itself, so **you cannot reassign it and you have actually to assign it along with its declaration**.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) more details about the `const` keyword, even though it is not specifically oriented to the use with the pointers.

Please even note that the following code should not compile for you are not assigning a value to the const pointer *p*:

```
int main() {
    int * const p;
}
```

The same is true for the following one:

```
int main() {
    int const i;
}
```

It doesn't depend on the fact that you are dealing with a pointer, instead it's how the `const` keyword actually works and should/can be used.

---

### More details about const and pointers

Anyway, I didn't see your whole code and it looks to me that your intent is not to have a const pointer, instead in your case it could help having a pointer to const (but it mainly depends on your problem, so I can be wrong).
How to define them depends on your purposes, of course.

You can either define it as a const pointer or a pointer to a const value, the means of which are slightly different (of course, you can also define a pointer as a const pointer to a const value, that is an easily deducible consequence of the others above mentioned).

The first one indicates that the pointer itself cannot be reassigned, thus you have to assign it during the declaration and that's all.
The second one instead define a pointer that is reassignable, but you can assign it only addresses of const variables of the given type (or better, even if they are defined as non const, they will be treated as const when accessed through that pointer, with all the limitations of the case).

It follows a brief example of the types of const pointer and pointer to const above mentioned:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    // pointer to const int
    int const *icp;
    // const pointer to int
    int * const cip = &i;
    // const pointer to const int
    int const * const cicp = &i;
    // this one can be reassigned, of course
    icp = &i;
}
```

Note also that `int const` and `const int` are interchangeable, so the declarations below are equivalent:

```
int const *p;
const int *p;
```

Obviously, this is not an exhaustive list. I've only tried to give you more details about how the `const` keyword can be used while defining a pointer and which are the intended means of those declarations.

Comment: I am aware of the difference between a const pointer and a pointer to a const. My question was specifically about the first case. Since its initial value is basically a non-value, why should you not be allowed to assign it once to the real value?

Comment: As stated in the response several times, you cannot modify it. Because of that, you must assign a value during the declaration.

Comment: Just clarifying some confusion in your response. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be glad, but please let me know what's unclear. No problem to clarify it.

Comment: @dspfnder: Its initial value is not "basically a non-value". I don't know where you've heard that. It is an unspecified value.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* const p;
```

declares `p` to be a pointer which cannot be changed, i.e. you cannot change where it points to once it is initialized. However, you can change the values it points to since the object type it points to is `int`.

```
int* const p = new int [10];
p = new int[20]; // Not OK
p[0] = 100;      // OK
```

Contrast that with

```
int const* p = new int [10];
p = new int[20]; // OK. You can change where the pointer points to.
p[0] = 100;      // Not OK. You cannot change the value of what p points to.
```